# IndexRoute doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router 1.0.3 and have the following route configuration:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={ History.createHistory() }>
  <Route path="/pages/home.aspx" component={ HomeView }>
    <IndexRoute component={ DefaultView } />
  </Route>
</Router>,
document.getElementById(appRoot.id));
```

When I browse to  `/pages/home.aspx`  the  `HomeView`  is rendered but without the  `DefaultView`  inside of it. I tried to debug it and noticed that the  `render()`  method of `HomeView` gets called, but the `render()`  method of  `DefaultView`  is not called.

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you rendering inside the `render` of `HomeView`?

Comment: @user2700659: it's a default behavior my friend it will not call all your router render method it will just call the default router for main content loading onto the page remaining route is registered when you use Link to call that router then it will redirect to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited answer:**

You need to place {this.props.children} within the render function of 'HomeView', which is essential within every view that contains child views (as with this situation)

As you're unsure about if it can still participate in routing, it will, just give it a try:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={ History.createHistory() }>
  <Route path="/pages/home.aspx" component={ HomeView } onEnter={HomeView.onEnter}>
    <IndexRoute component={ DefaultView } onEnter={DefaultView.onEnter} />
  </Route>
</Router>,
document.getElementById(appRoot.id));
```

and define the static onEnter in your 'DefaultView'/'HomeView'

```
React.createClass({
    statics: {
      onEnter(next, transition) {
        console.log('Hi from HomeView/DefaultView')
      }
    },
    render() {
      ....
    }
  });
```

Comment: That makes it render, but in this case, the DefaultView won't be a first class route component, and hence can't participate in routing. See this link for more info: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/IndexRoutes.md

Comment: Maybe you're misinterpreting the documentation. You're defining the IndexRoute with DefaultView, which makes it a first class component being able to perfectly participate in routing. But you will always have to place {this.props.children} within your parent views render, so it knows where to put the child views in your layout.

Comment: Thanks @quambo, your explanation makes sense. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to render the `children` in your parent component to render the child one. Check [Adding an Index](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#adding-an-index).

Somewhere in your `HomeView` render method (`div` is not required, added just for clarity):

```
<div>
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

In your case `this.props.children` will be a `DefaultView` element.